# Start Node.js Express server with child_process in new terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I am looking for a way to start a Node.js Express server using a detached child_process, and I would like to stream the output to a new terminal window.
Is this possible with Node.js somehow?

so I have this:

```
//server.js
var http = require('http');

const PORT=8080; 

function handleRequest(request, response){
    response.end('It Works!! Path Hit: ' + request.url);
}

http.createServer(handleRequest).listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

and then I want to start that server by running this file

```
//start-server.js
var cp = require('child_process');
cp.fork('./server.js');
```

I would like to open a new terminal and then run the start-server.js file...is this possible?

Comment: *I would like to open a new terminal and then run the start-server.js* - Do you want the program to open a terminal application and run the start-server.js file?

Comment: yeah that would work!

Comment: it would have to open bash I guess and then just run "node server.js"...if it's that easy? How can this be done without creating a bash script?

Comment: Have a look at projects like https://github.com/chjj/pty.js

Answer (score 3):

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
child;

child = exec('gnome-terminal -x node',
function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

add the file_name after the node command 
it will always start new terminal before running node js

refrence    : -   https://askubuntu.com/questions/401009/command-to-open-new-terminal-window-from-the-current-terminal/401012

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

combine these two ideas